# change image to another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to change a image to another image when the user clicks on the options they have of images or colors, i have a picture below to show what im trying to do
this are the links for second images
http://s24.postimg.org/6khgqwwg5/HM10_T_1004_BK_1.jpg
http://s4.postimg.org/6ualhzpex/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_BK.jpg

[image: color change]

html

```
<div class="container">
<p class="img-main">
<a href="#"   class="overlaybox-img">

<img src="http://coldcoffee.jp/resources/upload/products/thumbnail2/HM10-T-1004-WH.jpg">
</a> </p>
<div id="colorsAndAltContainer">
<ul class="">

    <li class="defaultColor selected">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="description">BLACK</div>
                        <div class="rgbColor" data-color="000000" style="background-color: #000000"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="description">WHITE</div>
                        <div class="rgbColor" data-color="FFFFFF" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>

    <div class="altImages">

   <ul class="alternativeImages">     
   <li class="selected">

        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="T-Shirt and Jersey" class="alternativeImage"  src="http://s21.postimg.org/ep27oalqr/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_1.jpg" width="54" height="54" >
        </li>
     </ul>
                </div>          

                </ul>
     </div> 
       </div>
```

css:

```
.container {
min-height: 565px;
width: 878px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 220px;
position: relative; 
}

 body{
background-color: #000;
 }
.img-main {
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
}
#colorsAndAltContainer {
position: relative;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 70px;
height: 300px;
float: left;
margin-left: 6px;
}
.inner {
cursor: pointer;
}
.description {
display: none;
}
.rgbColor {
border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
width: 13px;
height: 13px;
}
.selectColor {
float: left;
}

.selectColor ul {
float: left;
margin-right: 6px;
}
ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
}
.altImages {
position: absolute;
width: 70px;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
.alternativeImages {
bottom: 0;
}
.alternativeImages li {
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 6px;
}
img {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to do it in plain Javascript.

```js
function switchImages(){
  if(document.getElementById("mainImage").src != "http://s24.postimg.org/6khgqwwg5/HM10_T_1004_BK_1.jpg") {
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = "http://s24.postimg.org/6khgqwwg5/HM10_T_1004_BK_1.jpg";
    document.getElementById("smallImage").src = "http://s4.postimg.org/6ualhzpex/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_BK.jpg";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = "http://coldcoffee.jp/resources/upload/products/thumbnail2/HM10-T-1004-WH.jpg";
    document.getElementById("smallImage").src = "http://s21.postimg.org/ep27oalqr/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_1.jpg";
  }
     
  
}
```

```css
.container {
min-height: 565px;
width: 878px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 220px;
position: relative; 
}

 body{
background-color: #000;
 }
.img-main {
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
}
#colorsAndAltContainer {
position: relative;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 70px;
height: 300px;
float: left;
margin-left: 6px;
}
.inner {
cursor: pointer;
}
.description {
display: none;
}
.rgbColor {
border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
width: 13px;
height: 13px;
}
.selectColor {
float: left;
}

.selectColor ul {
float: left;
margin-right: 6px;
}
ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
}
.altImages {
position: absolute;
width: 70px;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
.alternativeImages {
bottom: 0;
}
.alternativeImages li {
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 6px;
}
img {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="img-main">
<a href="#"   class="overlaybox-img">

<img id="mainImage" src="http://coldcoffee.jp/resources/upload/products/thumbnail2/HM10-T-1004-WH.jpg">
</a> </p>
<div id="colorsAndAltContainer">
<ul class="">

    <li class="defaultColor selected">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="description">BLACK</div>
                        <div onclick="switchImages();" class="rgbColor" data-color="000000" style="background-color: #000000"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="description">WHITE</div>
                        <div onclick="switchImages();" class="rgbColor" data-color="FFFFFF" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>

    <div class="altImages">

   <ul class="alternativeImages">     
   <li class="selected">

        </li>
        <li>
            <img onclick="switchImage();" id="smallImage" alt="T-Shirt and Jersey" class="alternativeImage"  src="http://s21.postimg.org/ep27oalqr/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_1.jpg" width="54" height="54" >
        </li>
     </ul>
                </div>          

                </ul>
     </div> 
       </div>
```

Comment: why the small image when i click on it nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

First assign an ID to your T-shirt image:

```
<img id="t-shirt" alt="T-Shirt and Jersey" class="alternativeImage"  src="http://s21.postimg.org/ep27oalqr/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_1.jpg" width="54" height="54" >
```

Then on your black & white buttons assign a data attribute with the URL of the image the t-shirt will be changed to:

```
<div class="inner" data-image-id="http://urltoblackimage.jpg"></div>
```

Then use jQuery to change the image src on click:

```
$('div.inner').click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr('data-image-id');
    $('#t-shirt').attr('src', image);
});
```

Maybe give your div class="inner" a better trigger name with an ID or a more descriptive class name to avoid conflicts.

Comment: $(this).attr('data-image-id'); can simply be  $(this).data('image-id');

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the relevant `<a>` tag, access it with

`document.getElementById('idOfTag').setAttribute('href')='someOtherImage.jpg';`

This would just be several lines within a javascript function. Make the button, or whatever the user is clicking, listen and execute this function by adding `onclick="yourFunctionsName()`

No jquery necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way without changing anything in your existing code.

```
<script>
$().ready(function(){
$('#colorsAndAltContainer li').on('click',function()
{

  if($(this).find('.rgbColor').data('color') === "000000") 
  {
       $('a.overlaybox-img img').attr("src","http://s24.postimg.org/6khgqwwg5/HM10_T_1004_BK_1.jpg");
       $('.alternativeImage').attr("src","http://s4.postimg.org/6ualhzpex/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_BK.jpg");
  }   
  else if($(this).find('.rgbColor').data('color') === "FFFFFF") 
  {
    $('a.overlaybox-img img').attr("src","http://coldcoffee.jp/resources/upload/products/thumbnail2/HM10-T-1004-WH.jpg"); 
    $('.alternativeImage').attr("src","http://s21.postimg.org/ep27oalqr/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_1.jpg");
  }  
});

$('.alternativeImage').on('click',function()
{
  var smallImageUrl = $(this).attr("src");
  var mainImageUrl = $(".img-main img").attr("src");
  $(this).attr("src",mainImageUrl);  
  $(".img-main img").attr("src",smallImageUrl);
  $(".img-main img").css("width","300px");
});
});
</script>
```

Working link : http://jsfiddle.net/b2c5e19h/5/

Comment: why the small image when i click on it nothing happen

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you please elaborate the behavior ?

Comment: this one <img alt="T-Shirt and Jersey" class="alternativeImage"  src="http://s21.postimg.org/ep27oalqr/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_1.jpg" width="54" height="54" >

Comment: that small image is another view of the main image its just another option to choose

Comment: this is a picture to show what im trying to do http://s30.postimg.org/b6fh9zaxt/back.jpg

Comment: got it. Updated the solution and fiddle.